# How to find which column has been dragged at TListView.OnColumnDragged?

Tags: delphi, listview, drag

`OnColumnDragged` event of `TListView` has a simple `TNotifyEvent` type, so there is no straight way to find which column has been actually dragged into the new position.

How can I find which column has been dragged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a help of interposed class you might catch the [`HDN_ENDDRAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification code in the [`WM_NOTIFY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message handler.

The [`HDN_ENDDRAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification returns in the `lParam` parameter the [`NMHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure containing information about the header item that was being dragged. Here is the code sample; you can follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11775931/3) of the post as well:

```
uses
  ComCtrls, CommCtrl;

type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  private
    procedure WMNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotify); message WM_NOTIFY;
  end;

implementation

{ TListView }

procedure TListView.WMNotify(var AMessage: TWMNotify);
var
  HeaderHandle: HWND;
begin
  inherited;
  if (AMessage.NMHdr^.code = HDN_ENDDRAG) then
  begin
    HeaderHandle := ListView_GetHeader(Handle);
    if (AMessage.NMHdr^.hWndFrom = HeaderHandle) then
    ShowMessage(
      'The header with index ' +
      IntToStr(TWMNotifyHC(AMessage).HDNotify^.Item) + ' ' +
      'has been dragged to the position with index ' +
      IntToStr(TWMNotifyHC(AMessage).HDNotify^.PItem^.iOrder) + '. ' +
      'Columns are not updated yet!');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How do you relate `TWMNotifyHC(AMessage).HDNotify^.Item` to the column that was moved? I know the answer, but it's a nuance that you perhaps need to explain. And you may also care to show how to find out where this particular column has been dragged to.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, if you know the answer, please share it, it will really improve the solution.

Comment: @Andrew I already gave my answer. I think it's easier to stick to the VCL approach here rather than write low-level Win API code. I guess you aren't very keen on what I suggested.

Comment: Andrew, I've added [`some comments`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11775931/3) in a hope that will be understandable. @David, *you may also care to show how to find out where this particular column has been dragged to* - the question was *which column has been dragged* not where (but anyway it's `TWMNotifyHC(AMessage).HDNotify^.PItem^.iOrder` ;-)

Comment: @TLame yes, that detail was not asked, but it's highly likely you'd want to know where the column was dragged to and so it's nice to give that too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any indication which column has been moved. What does happen is that the items in the list view's `Columns` list are re-arranged to match the new order of the columns in the list view. So long as you can identify each column uniquely, and not by using the column's position in the list, then you can infer the order of the columns.

One possible approach is to give each column a different `Tag` value. Then you can do something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ColumnDragged(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  s := '';
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Columns.Count-1 do begin
    s := s + IntToStr(ListView1.Columns[i].Tag) + ' ';
  end;
  Caption := Trim(s);
end;
```

Naturally you'll want to do something more useful than this, but I trust that it gets the idea across.

Comment: The best might be to use the [`HDN_ENDDRAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775269(v=vs.85).aspx) notification.

Comment: @TLama The downside of that is that the `Columns` list will not match the new order because it has not yet been updated. Another problem is that you would need to derive a new control, use an interposer etc. which may be undesirable.

Comment: @David, but I still have no idea how to find which column has been dragged. Ok, we have the `Tag`'s state before and after the drag, in 2 arrays. How to detect which `Tag` has been dragged?

Comment: What is your underlying problem? Why exactly do you need to know which column was dragged? And do you need to know where it was dragged to? TLama's solution gives you what you are asking for. But forces you to get into Win API programming rather than sticking to the VCL functionality. The code in my answer would be useful if you wanted to update state based on the current, post-drag, ordering of the columns. That's often what you need to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Imagine 2 arrays: `1 2 3 4` and `1 3 2 4` - which column has been dragged, `2` or `3`?

Comment: If you need to know that then you'll have to do it TLama's way.

Comment: I think I need to mix up your both answers